# Select only top level UL in css

Tags: css, html-lists

Trying to select only the top level `UL` element and exclude any nested `UL` elements in CSS. I've tried so many different variations but can't find a solution.

As an example, the html code could look like something below. Now I want to go ahead and style only the top level `UL` and don't apply the styling to the nested `UL`s. In my scenario, I can't add any classes or IDs to the html code - no changes to the html, css only.

Thanks a lot!

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `parentSelector > ul` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Comment: I don't know the parentSelector I think. Would the parent selector be HTML (e.g. html > ul or body > ul)? I know for sure that the is not other UL element above the UL element I'm trying to style.

Comment: the parent selector is whatever you have that owns that element. There will always be a parent, even if it’s implicit (`<body>`). If there isn’t you should better qualify your question so we can help accordingly. If you take a peek at that link, the span example is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Since the ```ul``` can occur anywhere, I believe the parent element would always be different. Sometimes it could be a ```div```, sometimes something else. I believe ```body > ul``` is the best way to go since one thing I know for sure is that there won't be another ```ul``` element above the ```ul``` element I'm trying to style.

Comment: Thanks @soulshined! You gave me the hint I was totally missing. Didn't even consider ```body > ul``` to be an option. Appreciate it!

Comment: ah i see. I misinterpreted what you were saying. I thought you were saying you didn't have one, but you meant you don't know what the parent will be at any given time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I settled for `*:not(li) > ul` to only select top level `<ul>` elements and exclude `<ul>` elements that are inside of other `<ul>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) to capture anything that owns a 'ul', since you don't have insight. However, you do have insight in the sub lists so you can ensure you are only getting top-level by negating `li` elements that own one. Not sure what all your edge cases are but that's one way to do it.

```css
ul {
  background-color: pink; /* just for visual reference */
}

*:not(li)>ul {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>nav sub 1</li>
          <li>nav sub 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>nav 1</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>footer 1</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Otherwise you can just compound rules with all the elements that you think are possiblilites:

```css
div > ul,
nav > ul,
body > ul
...etc {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I believe I found the flaw in my logic. ```body > ul``` will only work if the direct parent element of ```<ul>``` is actually ```<body>```. Something like ```<body><div><ul>``` won't be selected by ```body > ul```. Is there a way to select the first ```<ul>``` element from ```<body>``` with a unknown number of elements in between?

Comment: Yes, see the second rule in my answer

Comment: That would not be very scalable imho. There could be a number of elements in between that are not immediately apparent. I wish there was something easier but I can make it work for now.

Comment: Is it is scaleable? `*` literally applies to any element. By using `:not` in conjunction you can make sure it’s not a child of an li at least. But you can always add more for your needs.

Comment: Did you even read the answer or check out the universal selector link?

Comment: Yes, I played around with your code snippet but didn't fully understand how ```*:not(li)>ul``` works. Now I believe it's clear. If I'm not mistaken, it basically does ```* > ul``` but excludes everything that's ```li > ul```.

Comment: Sounds good  so yes, `*` can be anything (div, nav, main, body) and if you need to exclude more elements that way, you can simply add another `:not`; `*:not(li):not(canvas)`